# React with Office UI Fabric - InputChildren not firing onSubmit/onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, jsx

Function:

```
  onMessageSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = this.message;
    if (!input.value) {
      return false;
    }
    this.pushMessage(this.state.curr_user, input.value);
    input.value = '';
    return true;
  }
```

Form:

```
<form onSubmit={e => this.onMessageSubmit(e)}>
    <InputChildren ref={m => { this.message = m; }} >
    <IconButton iconProps={ { iconName: 'Forward' } } onClick={e => this.onMessageSubmit(e)} /> 
    </InputChildren>
</form>
```

I have created an `Input` with a `Button` as a `Child` `Component` inside. I am able to create simple `onClick` with the `Button` but not able to trigger the above `function`.

However, using JSX `form` as shown below does seem to work:

```
      <form onSubmit={e => this.onMessageSubmit(e)}>
        <input
          ref={m => { this.message = m; }}
          placeholder="Write here.."
          className="message-input"
        />
      </form>
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong - any ideas? (I have also tried `onClick` on the `Button` without a `form` wrapper).

Thanks

Comment: For now I have just created an input but I'd ideally like to use the InputChild component and IconButton as the trigger.